# How can I strip a question mark and all the following characters from a character string?

Tags: automator

How can I create an automator action (to save as a system service) to strip a question mark and all the following characters from a character string?

For example, change this…

`https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html?action=click&algo=identity&block=editors_picks_recirc&fellback=false&imp_id=857225215&impression_id=9ec8fd81-a1ef-12eb-a9ba-2593f4310346&index=1&pgtype=Article&pool=editors-picks-ls&region=ccolumn&req_id=877591687&surface=home-featured&variant=0_identity&action=click&module=editorContent&pgtype=Article&region=CompanionColumn&contentCollection=Trending`

to this…

`https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html`

Comment: Tetsujin: Perfect! Thank you! I owe you a beer or something. user3439894: Yes, often URIs in an address bar, but I also want to remove tracking/user info from links people send me in emails, or ones I find elsewhere, before loading them with a browser.

Comment: user279030, RE: " but I also want to remove tracking/user info from links people send me in emails, or ones I find elsewhere, before loading them with a browser." --  Please see the **Notes:** section of my answer. I've added info for when selected text is not in an editable text field. Configuring the **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ with that option does not replace selected text but places the modified selected text on the **clipboard** to then be pasted where wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selected text (**URL** in this example) is in an editable field, .i.e. a text box or editable document, then you can create an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* setting **Workflow receives current [text] in [any application]** with **[√] Output replaces selected text**, adding a **Run AppleScript** *action* using either *example* **AppleScript** *code* below:

Here is one method you can use:

```applescript
set theString to "https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html?action=click&algo=identity&block=editors_picks_recirc&fellback=false&imp_id=857225215&impression_id=9ec8fd81-a1ef-12eb-a9ba-2593f4310346&index=1&pgtype=Article&pool=editors-picks-ls&region=ccolumn&req_id=877591687&surface=home-featured&variant=0_identity&action=click&module=editorContent&pgtype=Article&region=CompanionColumn&contentCollection=Trending"

set myString to ¬
    text items 1 thru ¬
        ((offset of "?" in theString) - 1) ¬
            of theString as text
```

Returns:

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html
```

---

Another method:

```
set theString to "https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html?action=click&algo=identity&block=editors_picks_recirc&fellback=false&imp_id=857225215&impression_id=9ec8fd81-a1ef-12eb-a9ba-2593f4310346&index=1&pgtype=Article&pool=editors-picks-ls&region=ccolumn&req_id=877591687&surface=home-featured&variant=0_identity&action=click&module=editorContent&pgtype=Article&region=CompanionColumn&contentCollection=Trending"

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "?"}
set myString to first text item of theString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
```

Returns:

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/13/books/review/somebooktitle.html
```

---

To use the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, in the **Run AppleScript** *action*, replace the default *code* with:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set theString to input as text
    
    set myString to ¬
        text items 1 thru ¬
            ((offset of "?" in theString) - 1) ¬
                of theString as text
    
    return myString
    
end run
```

Or:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set theString to input as text
    
    set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
        {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "?"}
    set myString to first text item of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    
    return myString
    
end run
```

---

**Notes:**

Either *example* of the **AppleScript** *code* will only return the *text* up to, but not including the *question mark* in any selected string of *text* that contains a *question mark*.

If the selected string of *text* does not contain a *question mark*, the selected string of *text* is replaced with itself.

---

The **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* as currently configured above does not avail itself to selected *text* that is not in an editable text field.

If you want to be able to select text that is not in an editable text field, then you can leave **[] Output replaces selected text** unchecked and replace `return myString` with `set the clipboard to myString`, which places the modified *string* on the **clipboard**, and from there you can paste it where you want.

Answer (score -3):

Since your intent (apparently) is to remove parameters from a URI, I’ll take a guess you’re dealing with links in web pages.

In that case, it might be worthwhile to create a JavaScript function that alters all links in the current page that way.  Then put it in the bookmarks of your browser.  When the need arises, click that to run the function, then click your modified links.

I’ve done something vaguely similar, but I’m not very good at JavaScript.  So I welcome someone else providing an implementation.